# jQuery CSS change on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to hide a division on the page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu1-holder').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

I need to change the CSS class to show the division on mouseover of the division with the class "**menu-item kitchens**"

I've tried the following code but not had any luck with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu1-holder').css('display', 'none');
    $("div.menu-items.kitchens").mouseover(function(){
        $('#menu1-holder').css('display', 'block');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('#menu1-holder').css('display', 'none');      
    });
});
```

Can someone please have a look at the code and give me some pointers?

Comment: Should `$("div.menu-items.kitchens")` be `$("div.menu-item.kitchens")`?

Comment: Have you would put a jsfiddle demo???

Comment: Works fine for me, so I'm guessing there's an error in your HTML?
By the way, jQuery has some nice hide() and show() methods for elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify things somewhat, with `.hover()`:

```
$('#menu1-holder').css('display', 'none');
    $("div.menu-items.kitchens").hover(function(){
        $('#menu1-holder').show();
    },function(){
        $('#menu1-holder').hide();
    });
```

I strongly suspect that any problems are with the selectors, though, rather than the jQuery methods/functions. The selector `$('div.menu-items.kitchens')` (a div with a class of 'menu-items' *and* a second class-name of 'kitchens') may well be correct, but seems a little over-precise, and possibly erroneous. If you publish your html mark-up that would help refine the solutions, and explain perhaps what was wrong in your own attempt.

References:

- [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `show` and `hide` should prove more robust and simpler, too :

```
$('#menu1-holder').show()
```

As for the rest of your code, make sure `menu-item` does not have a final S (your question is ambiguous), and add an alert, or console display, to the events to make sure the CSS selector is correct, and the event is actually fired.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the selector for "**menu-item kitchens**".  Are those two classes or one class?

Also - you might try the jQuery `show` and `hide` functions ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)).